# XSL Parsing a node's multiple attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to grab the airings/mediafile/startTime value of a node which has multiple attributes.

Here is a snippet of the XML:

```
<show epgId="DT523214136">
    <title>America Reframed</title>
    <description>9-Man Teams for this a competitive Chinese-American sport prepare for the national championship in Boston.</description>
    <airing channelId="129" duration="7200" sageDbId="6422008" startTime="2017-01-25T01:00:00.00Z">
        <manualRecord/>
        <recordSchedule duration="7200" startTime="2017-01-25T01:00:00.00Z"/>
        <mediafile duration="7200" sageDbId="6423032" startTime="2017-01-25T01:00:00.02Z" type="TV">
            <segmentList>
                <segment duration="7200" filePath="E:\Record\AmericaReframed-6422008-0.mpg" startTime="2017-01-25T01:00:00.02Z"/>
            </segmentList>
        </mediafile>
    </airing>
</show>
```

Here's what i have. I get no output for startTime. I've tried everything but xsl is confusing and arcane to me.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2></h2>
  <table WIDTH="100%" border="1" style="font-family:arial; font-size:   13px;" >
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Description</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Category</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Date</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="sageShowInfo/showList/show">
    <xsl:sort select="category"/>
    <xsl:sort select="title"/>
    <tr>
      <td width="30%"><xsl:attribute name="STYLE">color:A50F4B</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="title"/>: <xsl:value-of select="episode"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="category"/> </td>

<xsl:comment>this doesn't work: </xsl:comment>
      <xsl:for-each select="airing">
                 <td width="10%"><xsl:value-of select="substring(mediafile/startTime,1,10)"/></td>
     </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:comment>-------</xsl:comment>

    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute references are prefixed with `@`, so it should be

```
...mediafile/@startTime...
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement is trying to select the inner text of a startTime element inside of the mediafile element

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(mediafile/startTime,1,10)"/>
```

Instead you should be selecting the startTime attribute of the mediafile element:

```
<mediafile duration="7200" sageDbId="6423032" startTime="2017-01-25T01:00:00.02Z" ...
```

So your would use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(mediafile/@startTime,1,10)"/>
```

Comment: Excellent. That works. I spent forver trying to figure it out.